# Apple Healthkit - Trending HeartRate Function and Timer

Tags: swift, apple-watch, healthkit

I want to be able to start a timer when the trending heart rate is negative and stop the timer when the heart rate is trending positively. I have no problem getting the heart rate using statistics in HealthKit.

The issue is I need to call the function to check the trending heartRate every 5 seconds but using the function below won't start the timer. It will publish the heartRateDirection, but the timer never starts. If I call the function to start the Rest Timer from a button it works just fine.

```swift
@Published var heartRateDirection: Int = 0
private var getHeartRateTrendTimer: Timer?

func startGetHeartRateTimer() {
    getHeartRateTrendTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: true) { timer in
        self.heartRateTrendUpOrDown()
    }
}

// Read the three most recent reading and the three prior and return a direction
func heartRateTrendUpOrDown() {
    
    let last6fromHeartRateData = heartRateData.suffix(6)
    
    let sumFirst3Elements = last6fromHeartRateData.prefix(3).map{ $0.value }.reduce(0, +)
    let sumLast3Elements = last6fromHeartRateData.suffix(3).map{ $0.value }.reduce(0, +)
        
    if sumFirst3Elements == sumLast3Elements {
        print("Staying Flat")
        self.heartRateDirection = 0
    }else if sumFirst3Elements < sumLast3Elements{
        if self.heartRateDirection == 1 {
            print("Continuing to Go Up")
        } else{
            self.resting = false
            self.stopRestTimer()
            self.heartRateDirection = 1
            print("first time going up")
        }
    }else{
        if self.heartRateDirection == -1{
            print("Continuing to Go Down")
        }else{
            self.resting = true
            self.startRestTimer()
            self.heartRateDirection = -1
            print("first time going down")
        }
    }
}
```

I call the startGetHeartRateTimer() from a .onAppear on a view.

```swift
    Group{
        if resting{
             let minutes = currentRestTime / 60
             let remainingSeconds = currentRestTime % 60
             Text(String(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes, remainingSeconds))
                 .font(.title3)
                 .bold()
                 .foregroundColor(.green)
                                
        }else{
            Image(systemName: "figure.strengthtraining.traditional")
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .frame(height: 15)
        }
    }.onAppear{
        workoutManager.startGetHeartRateTimer()
    }
```

I am very, very new to swift and programming in general and if you have tips on cleaner code, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: what is your initial value of heartRateDirection? also, you should be able to walk through the code and see why the call is never made.

Comment: @johnelemans The initial value is 0, meaning that heart rate is flat. I did leave out a part in my question about calling startGetHeartRate(). I call it from an .onAppear on a Group that appears when based on another state change.